# glob files to use as input for a python script from a python script.

Tags: python, stdin, glob

Instead of

```
cat $$dir/part* | ./testgen.py
```

I would like to glob the files and then use stdin for ./testgen.py while inside of my python script. How would i do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could let the shell do it for you:

```
./testgen.py $$dir/part*
```

This passes every matching filename as a separate argument to your program. Then, you just read the filenames from `sys.argv[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `glob` and [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) could be used:

```
from glob import glob
import fileinput

for line in inputfile.input(glob('dir/part*')):
    print line # or whatever
```

Although if you get the shell to expand it - you can just use `inputfile.input()` and it will take input files from `sys.argv[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

nneonneo is correct about shell expansion, but it won't work on Windows. Here's a simple, totally bulletproof cross-platform version:

```
import sys
from glob import glob

def argGlob(args=None):
    if args is None: args = sys.argv

    return [subglob for arg in args for subglob in glob(arg)]
```

`argGlob` will return the exact same thing as Unix-style shell expansion, and it also won't screw up any list of args that's already been expanded.